# Adjusting Graph Layouts

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, visnetwork

I have the following graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

set.seed(123)
n=15
data = data.frame(tibble(d = paste(1:n)))

relations = data.frame(tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
))

data$name = c("new york", "chicago", "los angeles", "orlando", "houston", "seattle", "washington", "baltimore", "atlanta", "las vegas", "oakland", "phoenix", "kansas", "miami", "newark" )

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")

plot(graph, layout=layout.circle, edge.arrow.size = 0.2)
```

[image]

I tried to make this exact same graph using the "visNetwork" library, but the graph now appears "circular" instead of "random":

```
  visIgraph(graph)
```

[image]

I tried to look into whether its possible to produce a "random ordered" graph instead of a circular graph using the "visNetwork" library. For example:

```
 visIgraph(graph) %>%
 visLayout(randomSeed = 123)
```

But this still results in a circular graph.

I unexpectedly found this code that works instead (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visNetwork/versions/2.1.0/topics/visIgraphLayout):

```
visIgraph(graph) %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, hover = T), 
               nodesIdSelection = T)
```

[image]

Why does the "random seed" option still produce a circular graph, but the above option produces the desired result? Is there an explanation for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to fully understand what you are looking for but:

1. If you want the vertices to be placed randomly and not on a circle, you just need to use the argument `layout = "layout_randomly"` inside the `visIgraph()` function.
2. If you want the vertices to be placed randomly and on a circle, you need to use the `permute()` function and then just add the argument `layout = "layout_circle"` inside the `visIgraph()` function.

Please find below a reprex.

**Reprex**

- Your data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

set.seed(123)
n=15
data = data.frame(tibble(d = paste(1:n)))

relations = data.frame(tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
))

# data$name = c("new york", "chicago", "los angeles", "orlando", "houston", "seattle", "washington", "baltimore", "atlanta", "las vegas", "oakland", "phoenix", "kansas", "miami", "newark" )

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")
```

- Suggested code

  *1. Random vertex placement*

```r
visIgraph(graph, layout='layout_randomly')
```

[image]

*2. Random vertex placement on a circle*

```r
permute(graph, permutation = sample(vcount(graph))) %>% 
  visIgraph(layout='layout_in_circle')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>